# Importing a file is throwing error in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, shell

I am connecting to mongodb running on a VM from another linux machine through the command `db=connect("192.168.179.132:27017/database");`. I then try to import a json file from VM to the remote DB using the below command:

```
mongoimport --host 192.168.179.130 --port 27017 --db mydb --collection collection1  --file /home/user/new.json --jsonArray
```

There is no authentication so not included username and password in the command, when i execute the script i get below error

```
2015-09-24T07:54:08.198-0700 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Which is due to the import command (failing to execute). How do I import my json file to remote mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `mongoimport` is correct. It's the `new.json` file that's causing the issue. Are you sure it's valid JSON? You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to double-check.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the `new.json` file? What version of mongoimport are you using?